# .NET WebAPI 2 Posting Custom Model as JSON

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

might seem silly but I am unable to properly figure out the type for this property.

```
public class StoreViewModel
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string[] location { get; set; } <- This guy
}
```

I wanted to post a JSON in such a way:

```
{
    "name": "foo",
    "description": "bar",
    "location": {
        "latitude": 0.0,
        "longitude": 0.0
    }
}
```

Question, what's the Location property DataType to work with the default ModelState validation in the Controller?

Thanks!

Comment: In the JSON, notice that "location" isn't an array.

Comment: @Amy yeah but I don't want to create a location class with Id and whatever.

Comment: Why not?  That's how your JSON is structured.

Answer (score 2):

This an expected behaviour as you can see you location is `not an array`

You  have to change your `Model` to something like the following

```
public class Location
{
    public double latitude { get; set; }
    public double longitude { get; set; }
}

public class StoreViewModel
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public Location location { get; set; }
}
```